# Why do I get MouseDown events from a position outside of the control's boundary?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have a `Composite` containing a number of `Text` controls. I have attached `MouseListeners` to each control.

What surprises me is that sometimes, when I click on a control, I get a `MouseDown` event from its neighbour. The Event position is outside of the control's boundary and I get no event from the other control which I thought I had clicked on.

What can cause this to happen?

**SNIPPET**

Run. Press Esc to close the MessageBox. Click in field BBBB. Press Esc to close MessageBox. Click in field AAAA. The event is generated from field BBBB.

```
public class Test
{
    public class MyListener implements MouseListener, FocusListener
    {
        private boolean active;

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            message((Text) e.widget, "FocusGained");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        private void message(final Text t, final String m)
        {
            if (active == false)
            {
                active = true;
                MessageBox mb = new MessageBox(t.getShell());
                mb.setText(m);
                mb.setMessage(t.getMessage() + "\n\n" + m);
                mb.open();
                active = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            message((Text) e.widget, e.toString());
        }
    }

    private MyListener listener = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        new Test(shell);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public Test(Composite parent)
    {
        listener = new MyListener();
        create(parent);
    }

    private void create(Composite parent)
    {
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
        createText(parent, "AAAA");
        createText(parent, "BBBB");
        parent.layout(true);
    }

    private Text createText(Composite parent, String message)
    {
        Text t = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
        t.setMessage(message);
        GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
        t.setLayoutData(gd);
        t.addFocusListener(listener);
        t.addMouseListener(listener);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I assume you are using WindownBuilder plugin in Eclipse? Sometimes it generates wrong positions than what you see in the design view. If controls overlap they could cause this miss-fire also.

Comment: Can you provide a standalone snippet that demonstrates what you desribe?

Comment: The `x` and `y` position are widget-relative, i.e. based on the top left corner of the widget. Are you sure that what you're seeing is happening outside the widget? What does `MouseEvent#widget` refer to?

Comment: @Baz The widget property refers to the Text control which was not clicked on. The position is relative to that control and lies within the boundaries of the control which was clicked on

Comment: @bigneo Yes, I did use WindowBuilder but I use GridLayout and not absolute positioning. The controls do not overlap.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann snippet added

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed strange. When traversing from B to A, the MouseUp event is marked as sent from field B.

If you replace the MessageBox with something  non-interrupting i.e. `System.out`, the mouse event senders are the right ones.

To me, this seems more of a theoretical corner case. Decent applications would not interrupt the users field traversal with a modal window. However, if this is relevant for your, I'd [report a bug to SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php).

Comment: See my solution. The application wants a popup keyboard. I have decoupled the popup from the Text control events. That seems to have been the problem. Do you think a bug report is appropriate?

Comment: From the focus processing POV, your solution is the same as not calling the MessageBox at all - i.e. it doesn't get in the way. Yes, I think a bug report is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by de-coupling the pop-up window from the events. The `message` method now looks like this:

```
private void message(final Text t, final String m)
{
    //NB active is declared as 'volatile'
    if (active == false)
    {
        active = true;
        t.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                MessageBox mb = new MessageBox(t.getShell());
                mb.setText(m);
                mb.setMessage(t.getMessage() + "\n\n" + m);
                mb.open();
                active = false;
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Already active: " + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This seems to give the events the opportunity to continue uninterrupted by the pop-up window. The pop-up will be activated a short while later. So far it works ok.

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to declare `active` as volatile. There is still only a single thread involved. When `asyncExec()` is called from the UI thread like here, the runnable is simply added to the end of the message queue.